An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the IndexFaces operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3
I am getting this error while testing my aws apigateway on postman.
An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the IndexFaces operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3
I tried to give different permission to amazon Rekognition but i am getting same error again and again.

Can you share more information? Maybe the HTTP request and what your API gateway configuration looks like? And what IAM permissions have been granted? I don't think there is an obvious answer to your error, but I would probably start by ensuring the IAM role has the proper permissions
